# How can I check which option is selected in menu?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new writing.
I have a menu with a group, in the group I have `android:checkableBehavior="single"` inside there are two options to make visible or invisible a include layout inside of the main layout.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

private String settingSet = "kgcm";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

  //Creo el spinner de sexo
    final Spinner spinner1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerSexo);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinnerSexo, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    //Creo el spinner de edad
    Spinner spinner2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerEdad);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinnerEdad, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);  

    //Configuracion del boton
    Button bCalcular = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bcalcular);
    bCalcular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String sexo = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String imc1 = formulaDatos(spinner1);

            if (sexo.equals("Hombre"))
            {
                //Ficha de Hombre
                colocarIMCH(imc1);
                rellenarHombre(imc1);
            }
            else{
                //Ficha de Mujer
                colocarIMCM(imc1);
                rellenarMujer(imc1);
            }

        }
    });


    }

protected void rellenarMujer(String imc1) {
    if (imc1.compareTo("18.50") < 0){
        bajoPesoM();

    }
    else{
        if(imc1.compareTo("24.90") < 0){
            normalM();
        }
        else{
            if(imc1.compareTo("29.90") < 0){
                sobrePesoM();
            }
            else{
                if(imc1.compareTo("34.90") < 0){
                    obesidad1M();
                }
                else{
                    if(imc1.compareTo("39.9") < 0){
                        obesidad2M();
                    }
                    else{
                        obesidad3M();
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

protected void rellenarHombre(String imc1) {
    if (imc1.compareTo("18.50") < 0){
        bajoPeso();

    }
    else{
        if(imc1.compareTo("24.90") < 0){
            normal();
        }
        else{
            if(imc1.compareTo("29.90") < 0){
                sobrePeso();
            }
            else{
                if(imc1.compareTo("34.90") < 0){
                    obesidad1();
                }
                else{
                    if(imc1.compareTo("39.9") < 0){
                        obesidad2();
                    }
                    else{
                        obesidad3();
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

protected String formulaDatos(Spinner spinner1) {
    //configurando los editext para obtener el string
    EditText editTextAltura = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextAltura);
    EditText editTextPeso = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPeso);

    float altura = Integer.parseInt(editTextAltura.getText().toString());
    altura = altura / 100;
    float peso = Integer.parseInt(editTextPeso.getText().toString());


    float imc = (peso / (altura * altura));
    String imc1 = String.format("%.2f", imc);
    return imc1;
}

protected void bajoPeso() {
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio en Hombre TextView4
    TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewH4);
    String[] bph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bajoPesoH);
    int max = bph.length;
    tv4.setText(bph[getRandomNumber(max)]);

    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio deportuvo en Hombre TextView6
    TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewH6);
    String[] dph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bajoPesoHD);
    int maxd = dph.length;
    tv6.setText(dph[getRandomNumber(maxd)]);

}

protected void bajoPesoM() {
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio en Hombre TextView4
            TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewM4);
            String[] bph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bajoP);
            int max = bph.length;
            tv4.setText(bph[getRandomNumber(max)]);

            //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio deportuvo en Hombre TextView6
            TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewM6);
            String[] dph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bajoPD);
            int maxd = dph.length;
            tv6.setText(dph[getRandomNumber(maxd)]);

}

protected void normal() {
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio en Hombre TextView4
    TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewH4);
    String[] bph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.normalH);
    int max = bph.length;
    tv4.setText(bph[getRandomNumber(max)]);
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio deportuvo en Hombre TextView6
    TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewH6);
    String[] dph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.normalHD);
    int maxd = dph.length;
    tv6.setText(dph[getRandomNumber(maxd)]);

}
protected void normalM() {
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio en MUJER TextView4
            TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewM4);
            String[] bph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.normal);
            int max = bph.length;
            tv4.setText(bph[getRandomNumber(max)]);
            //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio deportuvo en TextView6
            TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewM6);
            String[] dph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.normalD);
            int maxd = dph.length;
            tv6.setText(dph[getRandomNumber(maxd)]);

}

protected void sobrePeso() {
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio en Hombre TextView4
    TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewH4);
    String[] bph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sobreH);
    int max = bph.length;
    tv4.setText(bph[getRandomNumber(max)]);
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio deportuvo en Hombre TextView6
    TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewH6);
    String[] dph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sobreHD);
    int maxd = dph.length;
    tv6.setText(dph[getRandomNumber(maxd)]);

}

protected void sobrePesoM() {
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio en MUJER TextViewM4
            TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewM4);
            String[] bph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sobreP);
            int max = bph.length;
            tv4.setText(bph[getRandomNumber(max)]);
            //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio deportuvo en TextViewM6
            TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewM6);
            String[] dph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sobrePD);
            int maxd = dph.length;
            tv6.setText(dph[getRandomNumber(maxd)]);

}

protected void obesidad1() {
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio en Hombre TextView4
    TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewH4);
    String[] bph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ove1H);
    int max = bph.length;
    tv4.setText(bph[getRandomNumber(max)]);
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio deportuvo en Hombre TextView6
    TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewH6);
    String[] dph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ove1HD);
    int maxd = dph.length;
    tv6.setText(dph[getRandomNumber(maxd)]);

}

protected void obesidad1M() {
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio en MUJER TextViewM4
            TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewM4);
            String[] bph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ove1);
            int max = bph.length;
            tv4.setText(bph[getRandomNumber(max)]);
            //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio deportuvo en TextViewM6
            TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewM6);
            String[] dph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ove1D);
            int maxd = dph.length;
            tv6.setText(dph[getRandomNumber(maxd)]);

}

protected void obesidad2() {
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio en Hombre TextView4
    TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewH4);
    String[] bph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ove2H);
    int max = bph.length;
    tv4.setText(bph[getRandomNumber(max)]);
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio deportuvo en Hombre TextView6
    TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewH6);
    String[] dph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ove2HD);
    int maxd = dph.length;
    tv6.setText(dph[getRandomNumber(maxd)]);

}

protected void obesidad2M() {
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio en MUJER TextView4
            TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewM4);
            String[] bph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ove2);
            int max = bph.length;
            tv4.setText(bph[getRandomNumber(max)]);
            //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio deportuvo en TextView6
            TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewM6);
            String[] dph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ove2D);
            int maxd = dph.length;
            tv6.setText(dph[getRandomNumber(maxd)]);

}

protected void obesidad3() {
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio en Hombre TextView4
    TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewH4);
    String[] bph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ove3H);
    int max = bph.length;
    tv4.setText(bph[getRandomNumber(max)]);
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio deportuvo en Hombre TextView6
    TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewH6);
    String[] dph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ove3HD);
    int maxd = dph.length;
    tv6.setText(dph[getRandomNumber(maxd)]);

}

protected void obesidad3M() {
    //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio en MUJER TextViewM4
            TextView tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewM4);
            String[] bph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ove3);
            int max = bph.length;
            tv4.setText(bph[getRandomNumber(max)]);
            //Colocar un consejo Aleatorio deportuvo en TextViewM6
            TextView tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewM6);
            String[] dph = (String[])getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ove3D);
            int maxd = dph.length;
            tv6.setText(dph[getRandomNumber(maxd)]);

}

protected void colocarIMCH(String imc1) {

    //cargar layout que vamos a usar
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_hombre);
    //Colacamos el IMC en el textView
    TextView textViewH2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewH2);
    textViewH2.setText(imc1);

}


protected void colocarIMCM(String imc1){

    //Cargar layout que vamos a usar
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_mujer);
    //Colacamos el IMC en el textView
    TextView textViewM2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewM2);
    textViewM2.setText(imc1);
}


protected int getRandomNumber(int max){

    int number = (new Random().nextInt(max));
    return number;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    View include = findViewById(R.id.includeinch);

    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.kgcm:
        if (item.isChecked());
        else{
            item.setChecked(true);
            settingSet = "kgcm";
            if(include != null){
            findViewById(R.id.includeinch).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.includekg).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        return true;
    case R.id.inch:
        if (item.isChecked());
        else{
            item.setChecked(true);
            settingSet = "inch";
            if(include != null){
            findViewById(R.id.includekg).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.includeinch).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        return true;

    case R.id.salir:
        salir();
        return true;
    case R.id.inicio:
        inici();
        return true;
    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

protected void salir() {
    finish();

}

private void inici() {

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

    if(settingSet.equals("inch")){
        findViewById(R.id.includekg).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.includeinch).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        findViewById(R.id.includekg).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.includeinch).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

}

I know that I can't do that:

`MenuItem menu = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.inch);
 MenuItem menu2 = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.kgcm);`

when I change something with the menu options and I back to main with `inici()` I hope, know witch option is selected in the menu to call the correct layout.

How can I check witch option it's selected in menu?
I'm so sorry by my English.

Comment: I cant't do that `MenuItem menu = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.inch);` Why, there isn't a menu item? How many views do you have? One or two. Why `setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);` and `onClose (null);`. Can you post the xaml? From what I understand, you want to show or hide specific layout depending on the selected menu item. This is correct? Without a global view of the code is hard to be able to help

Comment: When i asked "How many views do you have" i wanted to ask "How many activities..". Where you want to now witch option is selected in menu? Is in another activity or in `inici()` method. In any case you can pass this information. To inici() method by a parameter or using an object `Intent` if another `Activity`

Comment: I only have one activity. Five layouts: main, hombre, mujer, kgcm, inch.  Main, hombre, mujer is the full screen layout, kgcm is included in main layout, inch is included in layout but are invisible. Menu have three buttons, inicio,salir,settings. Settings have a submenu with kg_cm or inchh. Salir close app, inici back to main_layout, kg_cm and inchh you can see what do.

Comment: Let's get this straight: Main has in kgcm and inch but only one is visible at each time, also Main, hombre e mujer only on is visible at each time. So, if mujer is visible, when kgcm is selected and you call inici() to go back to Main you want kgcm visible and inch invisible, correct?

Comment: Kgcm or inch only can by visible in main_layout. When I press a button in main layout, do visible hombre or mujer. Inici() is to back main. Thanks again, Me explico como un libro cerrado.

Comment: I'm working in an example that I will post soon

Comment: Hello, your example work fine to solve my problem, but now, I have a new problem. I updated the main.java to show where is my problem. Like  I have two 'Sipinners' and a 'Button' when I call main label is not updated the Spinner and the Button Listener, you know How can I solve my problem? Thanks by your help

Comment: As you must understand I can not make the application for you. What I can say is that you are following an approach that is not correct in the development of Android applications. Whenever change the layout  to Main, through `setContentView`, the views in Hombre or Mujer can no longer be accessed. When you call `findViewById` it returns null. You should change your code so Hombre and Mujer be activities or fragments

Comment: Thanks to help me, I througth I should use activity, I'm really new programming and I must learn. I'm gonna change everything to build. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand this:

> When I back to main, if I change the case R.id.inch, this option not change to default, but my include back to default and then it's not working fine.

But I noticed the use of `return true` at the end of each `case`, replace that for `break`
and try it again.

The problem is that you are accessing views that do not exist because they are changed with `setContentView`
A example that works:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String SettingSet;//Save what choice is set. Will be used in inici()

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClickHombre(View v){

        setContentView(R.layout.hombre_layout);
    }

    public void onClickMujer(View v){

        setContentView(R.layout.mujer_layout);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        View include = findViewById(R.id.includeinch);

        switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.kgcm:
            if (item.isChecked());
            else{
                item.setChecked(true);
                SettingSet = "kgcm";
                if(include != null){//Do that only if in Main
                    findViewById(R.id.includeinch).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.includekg).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.inch:
            if (item.isChecked());
            else{
                item.setChecked(true);
                SettingSet = "inch";
                if(include != null){//Do that only if in Main
                    findViewById(R.id.includekg).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.includeinch).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }   
            }
            return true;

        case R.id.salir:
            salir();
            return true;
        case R.id.inicio:
                //this function back on to main layout
            inici();
            return true;
        default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void inici() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(SettingSet == "inch"){
            findViewById(R.id.includekg).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.includeinch).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            findViewById(R.id.includekg).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.includeinch).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void salir() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Anyway it is better to use an activity for Hombre and another for Mujer

There is a way around this but, i say again, it is not a good practice.

1 - Move all code from `onCreate` to `inici()`. Call `inici()` at `onCreate`.
2 - In `inici()` implement OnItemSelectedListener for each `Spinner` and save the selected item to a field.
3 - In `inici()` restore the item selected from that field.
4 - Before call `findViewById` with any view in Hombre or Mujer call `setContentView` with the corresponding layout (Hombre or Mujer). After all the work done with Hombre or Mujer call `inici()` (the screen may blink).
This can solve, but I am sure that other problems will come.

Comment: Wich difference are between true or break?

Comment: Menu it's working fine, it's the app. There are not error. I did the case R.id.inicio to go main layout, when I back to layout main, if I have changed the case R.Id.inch this case still true but my include R.id.includeinch of layout main switch off and shows a incorrect option.

Comment: As a matter of principle I think it is more correct to finish the "case" to "break" because I may have, in the end, code which must be executed whatever the case. After seeing your code more carefully I see that in fact this is not the problem. Still do not understand your problem. Describe each step you do, what you expect to happen and what actually happens. You can do it in Spanish, I'm Portuguese. It can also help if you post more code.

Comment: Instead of putting the code here you can edit your question and put it there

Comment: I'm new writing here. Edited my question